# Codeception bash color output does not display

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, cygwin, git-bash

I have been testing with Codeception and PhantomJS for a while, but when ever i have to debug and run

```
    vendor/bin/codecept run --debug
```

with colors set to true all i get is:

```
    Modules: ←[33mWebDriver, AcceptanceHelper←[39m
```

and so on... So for some reason the color is just outputed in a raw format and is not working at all. Colors usually work. like when i use "ls --color" it just works.
My System is Windows 7 i'm using the "git bash" and i have also tried the regular "cmd" "powershell" and "cygqwin". Neither one of them seem to work with codeceoptions output.
So what is the problem? I'm clueless :(

Comment: could you add the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: programs shouldn't assume that the color codes are going to be ansi escape sequences - though they usually are - the way it is supposed to go is 'tput setaf <color number>' (or setab, or sgr0 to reset) not all programs do this. Please give us a copy of your 'infocmp' so we can see your (not compiled) termcap!

Answer (score 3):

in bash, try running

```
export TERM=ansi
```

or

```
export TERM=xterm
```

before running your program

or, to test color output from the shell itself:

```
echo -e "\e[41m\e[32mCOLOR\e[0m"
```

if that does work than it is the program, not the environment

finally, you might just need a better console. 
try conemu, it has excellent ansi color support and i use it for cmd powershell bash perl and ssh sessions :) 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/

Comment: Bash doesn't process ANSI from children processes, only mintty is doing that. So, changing TERM will not have any effect most probably.

Answer (score 1):

Your application (Codeception) was not adapted to Windows console, which doesn't support ANSI colorizing. To enable ANSI colors you may choose one of the following options:

- [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) is the Windows local terminal with [ANSI capabilities](https://conemu.github.io/en/AnsiEscapeCodes.html) and many other features like tabs, splits, preconfigured shell tasks, ... Also, it's the only terminal which able to ["replace" default Windows console](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html). Yep, I'm the author.
- Some applications may work properly in mintty (bundled with cygwin or msys). Many native Windows console tools can't work properly in this terminal, but may be your app will be fine.
- There is AnsiCon project. It enables ANSI colorizing in standard Windows console.

BTW, bash's ls (cygwin or msys) was adapted to Windows console API, so it doesn't post ANSI to terminal, unless terminal has done special initialization of POSIX subsystem. ConEmu can do this initialization via [cygwin/msys connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html).